# How to subtract every adjacent line from the 2nd column and keep the first one

Tags: awk, command-line, bioinformatics

I am creating a file via this command:

```
awk '{print $2 " "$7" "$8}' REACTOME_EXTENSION_OF_TELOMERES.xls |  awk '$8!="No"  {print $1 " " $2}' | awk 'NR>1' | awk 'BEGIN { OFS=", "; print "Name" " " "0" };{ print $0 " " "" }'
```

The output is this:

```
    Name 0
WRAP53 0.08495288 
NHP2 0.17606254 
POLA1 0.25320756 
POLD3 0.32372433 
PRIM1 0.38140765 
RFC5 0.44302294 
POLD1 0.497649 
...
```

I need a command which would subtract every adjacent line in 2nd column and give me this result:

```
WRAP53 0.0849529 
NHP2 0.0911097 
POLA1 0.077145 
POLD3 0.0705168 
PRIM1 0.0576833 
RFC5 0.0616153 
POLD1 0.0546261 
...
```

I know how to do it when I just keep the 2nd column, it would be like this:

```
awk '{print $2 " "$7" "$8}' REACTOME_EXTENSION_OF_TELOMERES.xls |  awk '$8!="No"  {print $1 " " $2}' | awk 'NR>1' | awk 'BEGIN { OFS=", "; print "Name" " " "0" };{ print $0 " " "" }' | awk '{print $NF}' | awk 'NR-1{print $0-p}{p=$0}'
```

But how to do it so that I preserve the 1st column as shown above?

REACTOME_EXTENSION_OF_TELOMERES.xls  file looks like this:

```
NAME    PROBE   GENE SYMBOL     GENE_TITLE      RANK IN GENE LIST       RANK METRIC SCORE       RUNNING ES      CORE ENRICHMENT
row_0   WRAP53  null    null    163     1.5818238258361816      0.08495288      Yes
row_1   NHP2    null    null    201     1.5055444240570068      0.17606254      Yes
row_2   POLA1   null    null    283     1.3435969352722168      0.25320756      Yes
row_3   POLD3   null    null    367     1.240567684173584       0.32372433      Yes
row_4   PRIM1   null    null    501     1.1049883365631104      0.38140765      Yes
row_5   RFC5    null    null    557     1.0596935749053955      0.44302294      Yes
row_6   POLD1   null    null    653     1.0035457611083984      0.497649        Yes
```

It would be great if I could have the output of the whole command into: REACTOME_EXTENSION_OF_TELOMERES.y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire awk pipeline can be replaced by

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $8 != "No" {print $2, $7 - prev} {prev = $7}' REACTOME_EXTENSION_OF_TELOMERES.xls
```

which outputs

```
WRAP53 0.0849529
NHP2 0.0911097
POLA1 0.077145
POLD3 0.0705168
PRIM1 0.0576833
RFC5 0.0616153
POLD1 0.0546261
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $8 == "No" { next } { tmp = $7 } NR > 2 { $7 -= prev } { prev = tmp; print }' inputfile
NAME    PROBE   GENE SYMBOL     GENE_TITLE      RANK IN GENE LIST       RANK METRIC SCORE       RUNNING ES      CORE ENRICHMENT
row_0   WRAP53  null    null    163     1.5818238258361816      0.08495288      Yes
row_1   NHP2    null    null    201     1.5055444240570068      0.0911097       Yes
row_2   POLA1   null    null    283     1.3435969352722168      0.077145        Yes
row_3   POLD3   null    null    367     1.240567684173584       0.0705168       Yes
row_4   PRIM1   null    null    501     1.1049883365631104      0.0576833       Yes
row_5   RFC5    null    null    557     1.0596935749053955      0.0616153       Yes
row_6   POLD1   null    null    653     1.0035457611083984      0.0546261       Yes
```

The `awk` program, annotated with comments:

```awk
# Set output delimiter to input delimiter (tab, set with -F)
BEGIN { OFS = FS }

# Skip lines whose 8th column is "No"
$8 == "No" { next }  # or { exit } if "No"-lines are sorted at the end.

# Save the original value in column 7.
{ tmp = $7 }

# For any row past both the header and the first data line,
# decrease column 7 by the previous row's column 7 value.
NR > 2 { $7 -= prev }

# Remember the current row's original column 7 value
# in prev and print the (possibly) modified row.
{
    prev = tmp
    print
}
```

Redirect the output to a new filename to store it:

```
awk '...as above...' inputfile >outputfile
```

Comment: Thanks I had to tweak it a little bit because I have this Yes/No condition on teh 8th column but yes it is along these lines: awk '$8!="No"  {print}' ISHIDA_E2F_TARGETS.xls | awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { tmp = $7 } NR > 2 { $7 -= prev } { prev = tmp; print }' | awk '{print $2 " "$7}' > ISHIDA_E2F_TARGETS.GY

Comment: @anikaM What should happen if the 8th column says `No`?  It's _very seldom_ necessary to pipeline two `awk` programs together.

Comment: @anikaM I've updated.

Comment: well if it say "No" then I don't want it in my output, I just want rows where it says "Yes" , that is why I put: awk '$8!="No". Also it is space separated file

Comment: @anikaM It can't be a space separated file as there are a variable number of spaces between each column. If the columns are separated by multiple spaces, just remove `-F '\t'`.  What should happen with the calculation of column 7 if the previous row was deleted since it contained `No` in its 8th column?

Comment: they are ordered, so first are Yes rows and after are No rows, so that probelm won't occur